# Accessing contents with Loader class such as Content resolvers do?

Tags: android, multithreading, cursor, classloader, android-contentprovider

I am a bit confused about CursorLoader and a regular call with the Content Resolver :

- There is an example with the CursorManager : (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html) ,
  where we use `return new CursorLoader` to fetch the data.
- And another example with contentResolver, to insert some data in the content Provider :

`mUri = getContentResolver().insert(intent.getData(), null);`

What if we wanted to use a `Loader` instance to insert data in the content provider, instead of, like in the example above, just query the data. How should we do? And would it be necessary?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loaders are not for insert/update/delete queries, only for loading data. You'd want to use an [AsyncQueryHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncQueryHandler.html) to do those operations (best for operations tied to user interactions):

```
AsyncQueryHandler handler = new AsyncQueryHandler(getContentResolver()) {
    @Override
    protected void onInsertComplete(int token, Object cookie, Uri uri) {
        // Do something now that your insert is complete
    }
};
handler.startInsert(
    0, // token, passed on to onInsertComplete
    null, // cookie, passed on to onInsertComplete
    initialValues); // ContentValues to insert
```

Comment: Thank you ianhanniballake !